# closing iframe on esc key or clicking anywhere else

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

i want to close the iframe box as soon as i hit `esc` or i click outside the iframe area at the moment i have to click back on `hideshow` icon to hide the iframe again is there a method that i can use to close the iframe with `esc` or clicking outside the iframe area

**index.php**

```
<div id="msg_pic">
        <a class="msg_pic_link" id="hideshow"><span><img src="emptymsg.png" width="21px" height="21px"/></span></a>
        </div>

<div id="message" >
                <iframe id="iframe" style=" border-color:#080000; background-color: white ;" src="conversation.php" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
            </div>
```

**hide-show.js**

```
$('#hideshow').on("click", function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $("#message").toggle();

});
```

**mycss.css**

```
#message
{
display:none;
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1; 
}
```

the question how can i press esc key or click outside the `msg_pic_link` div to close `message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$(window).on("click keydown")` , `.is()`

```js
$('#hideshow').on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  $("#message").toggle();
  $(window).focus()
});

$(window).on("click keydown", function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault()
  if (e.keyCode === 27 || !$(e.target).is(function() {
    return $("#message, #hideshow")
  })) {
    $("#message").hide()
  }
}).focus()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg_pic">
  <a class="msg_pic_link" id="hideshow"><span><img src="emptymsg.png" width="21px" height="21px"/></span></a>
</div>

<div id="message">
  <iframe id="iframe" style=" border-color:#080000; background-color: white ;" src="conversation.php" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pb47m0om/2/

Comment: did not work i still have to click on the `hideshow` div to hide the iframe

Comment: @jake123 See updated post , substituted `window` for `document` , added `.focus()` to `window`

Comment: Nope still no luck  same thing happens

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5jzUD/9/ its needs to be like this but for some reason i cant achieve it

Comment: danmit it 
my fault m sorry i see what i was doing wrong now

Comment: @jake123 _"check for edited codes plz"_ ? Not certain what Question is ? Both lines within `click` handler of `$('#hideshow')` appear invalid . At first line , `$('#hideshow')` does not have `val()` , at second line `$("#message").toggle();class="msg_pic_link" is syntax error
`

Comment: the question is the same but the jquery code was wrong that time now i corrected but i still want to know how can i press esc key or click outside the `msg_pic_link` div to close `message`

Comment: _"still want to know how can i press esc key or click outside the msg_pic_link div to close message"_ ? Tried stacksnippets ?, jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/pb47m0om/ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96454/discussion-between-jake123-and-guest271314).